# c++ boost would async_read_some be blocked by buffer if the buffer is being fill by a data stream?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

For example, if a server is sending a packet of bit stream to my tcp client, and I am beginning to use async_read_some to retrieve it.

Is this async_read_some operation might retrieve only part of the packet from the buffer, or is the buffer mutable so the async_read_some would be blocked until this packet stream is fully arrived?

Comment: Assuming TCP: 'packet stream is fully arrived' - a stream canot be said to have 'arrived' - it's a byte stream.  Another byte or bytes may turn up at any time.

Comment: Thx Martin. Let say the packet is 1000 bytes and is the only thing send through the channel. Would the buffer lock other reader when it is being fill?

Comment: What "other reader"? Do you have two processes/threads reading from the same socket? `async_read_some` by design does not block anything, it's even part of the function name: `async`. When the callback is called, it may be with all data read, no data read (in case of error or socket closed), some of the data read, but never more than requested.

Comment: sorry, I was vague on the "buffer" term, I wasn't talking about the buffer that I created in my program. Joachim has answered the question anyway.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg you should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TCP, async_read_some might retrieve only part of the stream, and there are no blocking in the sense of user program.